# Python multiple clients chatting across a server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

The server is not broadcasting the sent messages back to the clients. The server is also not seeing the messages but is seeing that there is something being sent via the broadcast. The client who sends the message should not be sent the message again.

## ChatClient

```
import socket, threading

def send():
    while True:
        msg = raw_input('\nMe : ')
        cli_sock.send(msg)

def receive():
    while True:
        sen_name = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        data = cli_sock.recv(1024)

        print('\n' + str(sen_name) + ' : ' + str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    # socket
    cli_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # connect
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    cli_sock.connect((HOST, PORT))     
    print('Connected to remote host...')
    uname = raw_input('Enter your name to enter the chat : ')
    cli_sock.send(uname)

    thread_send = threading.Thread(target = send)
    thread_send.start()

    thread_receive = threading.Thread(target = receive)
    thread_receive.start()
```

## ChatServer

```
import socket, threading

def accept_client():
    while True:
        #accept    
        cli_sock, cli_add = ser_sock.accept()
        uname = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        CONNECTION_LIST.append((uname, cli_sock))
        print('%s is now connected' %uname)
        thread_client = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_usr, args= 
[uname, cli_sock])
        thread_client.start()

def broadcast_usr(uname, cli_sock):
    while True:
        try:
            data = cli_sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print "{0} spoke".format(uname)
                b_usr(cli_sock, uname, data)
        except Exception as x:
            print(x.message)
            break

def b_usr(cs_sock, sen_name, msg):
    for client in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if client[1] != cs_sock:
            client[1].send(sen_name)
            client[1].send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    CONNECTION_LIST = []

    # socket
    ser_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    ser_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

    # listen    
    ser_sock.listen(1)
    print('Chat server started on port : ' + str(PORT))

    thread_ac = threading.Thread(target = accept_client)
    thread_ac.start()
```

The expected should be if user is Dan(me):

John: Hi

Me: Hi

Me: How are you

John: Great

Stephen: Awesome

The actual is only displaying the "Me" on the specific client's side